# Can one deduce the uniformly continuity by a "weak" Lipschtz condition?

Tags: calculus

> $\exists L>0,$ such that for an arbitrary subinterval $I\subset[a,\infty),\exists x_1,x_2\in I$,we have $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<L|x_1-x_2|$$

This condition is much weaker than the Lipschtiz condition ,  can one deduce the the uniformly continuity of $f$ on $[a,\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, one cannot. In fact, there are discontinuous functions satisfying the condition. Take for example the famous function continuous only at the irrationals: $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational, and $f(p/q)=1/q$ if $p/q$ is a rational number given in its lowest terms. [It can be shown](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~tvogel/gallery/node6.html) that $f$ is continuous precisely at the irrational points. It obviously satisfies your condition with $L=1$ because every interval contains distinct irrational numbers. However, it cannot be uniformly continuous, because it is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The non-uniformly continuous function, $C^1$ function $f(x) = x \sin x$ satisfies your criterion, because it has a sequence of critical points $x_n$ that approach infinity. For any critical point $x$ of any $C^1$ function $f$ and for any value of $L$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that your inequality is true for all $x_1,x_2 \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$.

When I think of the $L$-Lipschitz condition, I like to remember one of its properties: if $f$ is differentiable and $L$-Lipschitz then $|f'(x)| \le L$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$. I concocted my example so that $f(x)$ has two phenomena: many critical points, and points with larger and larger derivative.